# Trying to change a sticky header background whenever a certain class hits the top of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple sticky header that I want to change the background color of whenever a div/class/id hits the top of the window (and changes back when scrolled up). Not just once but multiple times.

Base code for the sticky header is this, https://jsfiddle.net/wzrfg2xe/1/

HTML Code:

```
<div class="sticky-element-positioner">
<div class="sticky-element">
<nav class='greedy-nav'>
<ul class='visible-links'>
<li><a href='#'>Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>

<section class="one"> blabla</section>
<section class="two"> blabla</section>
<section class="three"> blabla</section>
<section class="four"> blabla</section>
<section class="five"> blabla</section>
```

CSS

```
ul { margin: 0; }
.greedy-nav {
height: 40px;
position: relative;
min-width: 250px;
width: 100%;
background: #513e5d;
width: 100%;
text-align: center; }

.greedy-nav a {
display: block;
padding: 0 30px;
line-height: 40px;
font-size: 16px;
color: #ddd;
text-decoration: none; }

.greedy-nav a:hover { color: #fff; background: rgba(0,0,0,.1); }

.greedy-nav .visible-links { display: inline-table; }
.greedy-nav .visible-links li { display: table-cell; }
.greedy-nav .visible-links li:first-child { font-weight: bold; }
.greedy-nav .visible-links li:first-child a { color: #fff !important; }

.sticky-element,
.sticky-element-positioner {
height: 40px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
z-index: 5; }

.sticky-element { position: static; }

.sticky-element.sticky-element-sticky {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
margin: 0; }

.sticky-element-positioner { position: static; }

.one { background: green; height: 300px; }
.two { background: yellow; height: 300px; }
.three { background: red; height: 300px; }
.four { background: blue; height: 300px; }
.five { background: orange; height: 800px; }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var stickyElement = $('.sticky-element'),
stickyElementPositioner = $('.sticky-element-positioner');

function stickyElementFixed() {
stickyElement.addClass("sticky-element-sticky");
}

function stickyElementStatic() {
stickyElement.removeClass("sticky-element-sticky");
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
var elementTarget = (stickyElementPositioner.offset().top);
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scrollTop <= elementTarget) {
stickyElementStatic();
} else {
stickyElementFixed();
}

});

});
```

I searched around and found this answer on stack on how it could work, jsfiddle.net/8onnaqL7/ (taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872003/add-class-when-element-reaches-top-of-viewport)).

Adding them together gives me this, http://jsfiddle.net/tpuqtobo/

It seems like it completely removes the whole sticky header styling now. I've tried numerous different ways to make it work but I just can't figure it out.

Is there any way to achieve what I am looking for without using a plugin where you sort of guess how far you have scrolled down from the top of the window?

Just to clarify, on the real design the sticky header appears below the header, so it's not at the top from the start.

If there is maybe another way to handle both the sticky and the changing of the background colors I am open to hearing any suggestions that might work.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code for `removeClass()` is removing all the classes including the `greedy-nav` class, which causes your nav to break.

Instead of just adding your `project-x` class, you should do :

```
$(".greedy-nav").removeClass().addClass("greedy-nav project2");
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tpuqtobo/1/

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: @excelsi Please mark as accepted answer if it solved your problem so that it can help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".greedy-nav").removeClass().addClass("greedy-nav project1");
```

You removed all classes include `greedy-nav` so need to add again for css styling.

Comment: Thank you, this was the thing I overlooked and it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this only with css, but you need to add

```
.sticky-element.sticky-element-sticky .greedy-nav {
    background: red;
}
```

not only

```
.sticky-element.sticky-element-sticky {
    background: red;
}
```

because your main background header styling is on `.greedy-nav` element.

Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

### You need to use [scroll](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) method

Please  try below With **working snippet code**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);  
    
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        
        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
      
        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.light-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#menu-center {
    width: 980px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu-center ul {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#menu-center ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    display: inline;
}
.active {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
a {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#Menu1 {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(images/home-bg2.png);
}
#Menu2 {
    background-image: url(images/portfolio-bg.png);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#Menu3 {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#Menu4 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1 menu">
    <div id="menu-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#Menu1">Menu1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Menu2">Menu2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Menu3">Menu3</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Menu4">Menu4</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Menu1"></div>
<div id="Menu2"></div>
<div id="Menu3"></div>
<div id="Menu4"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it will work as well. I will try both your method and @Gurtej Singh's method and see which will work the best for my needs. Thanks again!

Comment: @excelsi - glad to help you .... if you found your solution please `upvote` and mark as `accept` .. It will helps other to find correct answer.