# trigger event after x seconds (waypoints.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I have a page with 20 sections. Each section have a different background-color. The background-colors change via fade with the help of waypoints.js:

```
var inview = new Waypoint.Inview({
  element: $('#trigger00')[0],
  enter: function(direction) {
    $("#bgwrap").animate({
      backgroundColor: '#fff'
    }, 'slow');
  },
})

var inview = new Waypoint.Inview({
  element: $('#trigger01')[0],
  enter: function(direction) {
    $("#bgwrap").animate({
      backgroundColor: '#51FFCB'
    }, 'slow');
  },
})

// etc.
```

Now the problem is, that when I, lets say, scroll through 5 sections. The section background-color change 5 times.

How can I tell this script, that it should fire ONLY when a element is in the viewport for x seconds? I tried this with setTimeout, but only gotten a delay and not the effect I wanted. I want to change the background-color only if the element #trigger00 was in the viewport for x seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Note, jQuery animate will not work for `background-color`, it only works for numeric properties. You could use css transition for smoother effects.
You could use `setTimeout`. Also the issue with your code is that you are using `#bgwrap` same element for all blocks, you should use different elements.

Here is an example of something similar you are trying to achieve

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('block2'),
  handler: function(direction) {
   setTimeout(function(){
    $("#block2").css('background-color', '#fff');       }, 500)
  }
}); 
new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('block3'),
  handler: function(direction) {
   $("#block3").css('background-color', '#2ecc71');
  }
}); 
 new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('block4'),
  handler: function(direction) {
$("#block4").css('background-color', '#e74c3c');
  }
});
});
```

```css
.block{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #ffe;
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="block1" class="block block1">
 <span>Block1</span>
</div>
<div id="block2" class="block block2">
 <span>Block2</span>
</div>
<div id="block3" class="block block3">
 <span>Block3</span>
</div>
<div id="block4" class="block block3">
 <span>Block4</span>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/noframework.waypoints.min.js">
 </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps. Here is a jsbin of the above snippet https://jsbin.com/mohonuv/edit?html,js,output

Comment: my script works. with jquery ui it is possible to animate background-color. i just want to add the possibility that my backgrounds are changing if the trigger is x seconds in the viewport you know? i need some thing like "if (this-happens) for x seconds (do-this)"

Comment: Yes you could animate background with jQuery ui, you can use setTimeout, but as you are using one single element(#bgwrap) for changing colour, all of the background colour will change 4-5 times depending on how many waypoint you have.  Consider using different elements for each waypoint background. Could you add html for your code? Without html I have to take few guesses and answer this question.

Comment: Hmm okay, I do understand. But I have only this one fullscreen-div (#bgwrap) - and this div should change the background-color triggered by the waypoints, you know? How could I do this with ONE single div?

Comment: Could you share relevant html for your js code? Is #bgwrap parent element of these waypoints?

Answer (score 0):

This type of question has been answered in a different context.

Please see here: [Add class when element reaches top of viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872003/add-class-when-element-reaches-top-of-viewport)

Instead of only changing the background-color you can use css3 animate with an animation-delay in order to accomplish what you are looking for. Alternatively, you could just add a transition-delay.

Please let me know if you'd like to see an updated fiddle.