# Highlighting nav links when scrolling inside a container with overflow properties

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a container that has a lot of variable content inside. I wrote a function to highlight the nav link in navbar when the mouse hovers over that section. My PM wants the section to be highlighted depending on what section is presently being presented to the user. How do I find the div's offset position inside the container in relation to what is above the fold? Does this position even change in a scrollable container? I'm lost and have been hacking at this for a couple of days and it's now holding up pushing the code.

I've tried multiple times to calculate this with offsetHeight and offsettop but these values don't change. I can't use jquery.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  function refactorNavAnimation() {
    var sections = document.querySelectorAll(".refactor-section"),
        contentWrapper = document.querySelector(".listing-page-content");
    console.log(sections);

    contentWrapper.addEventListener("wheel", function() {
      sections.forEach(function (section) {
        var id = section.getAttribute("id"),
          activeSection = document.querySelector("a[href= '#" + id + "']"),
          position = section.offset;
        console.log(position);

        if (position <= 100) {
          console.log(position);
          removeActiveNavClass();
          activeSection.classList.add('active-nav-link');
        } else {
          removeActiveNavClass();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  refactorNavAnimation();
});
```

```
<main class="listing-page-content">
        <% if @open_negotiations.size > 0 || @closed_negotiations.size > 0 %>
          <section class="refactor-section" id="history-details-container">
            <%= render partial: "listings/partials/history/listing_page_history_wrapper", locals: {negotiation: @negotiation} %>
            <%# render partial: "refactor/partials/history/history-negotiation-header", locals: {negotiations: @negotiations} %>
            <%# render partial: "refactor/partials/history/this-negotiation", locals: {negotiations: @listing.negotiations} %>
          </section>
          <hr class="refactor-section-divider" id="hr-1">
        <% end %> 

        <section class="refactor-section" id="listing-details-container">
          <%= render partial: "listings/partials/listing_details", locals: {listing: @listing} %>
        </section>

        <hr class="refactor-section-divider" id="hr-2">

        <section class="refactor-section" id="estimator-container">
          <%= render partial: "listings/partials/estimator", locals: {listing: @listing} %>
        </section>

        <hr class="refactor-section-divider" id="hr-3">

        <section class="refactor-section" id="faqs-container">
          <%= render partial: "listings/partials/faqs", locals: {listing: @listing} %>
        </section>

        <hr class="refactor-section-divider" id="hr-4">

        <section class="refactor-section" id="stadium-details-container">
          <%= render partial: "listings/partials/stadium_info", locals: {listing: @listing} %>
        </section>

        <hr class="refactor-section-divider" id="hr-5">

        <section class="refactor-section" id="other-listings-container">
          <%= render partial: "listings/partials/other_listings", locals: {listing: @listing} %>
        </section>

      </main>
```

Comment: `position = section.offset` should be `position = section.offsetTop`

Comment: that just gives me the same value when I log it over and over again. The offset value doesn't change inside the container

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Use scrollTop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Comment: That, when logged, gives me zeros. But it does highlight the last link, so I've got that going for me.

Comment: Get the scrollTop from `window`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872003/add-class-when-element-reaches-top-of-viewport